In Pyomo, Why Does the Instance of a Variable Differ from the Variable Value in the Objective Function?
The goal is to minimise total investment costs over a period of time subject to a minimum investment constraint. The dependent variable, X, is the amount of investment in project i at time period t. The parameter Y defines the cost per unit of the dependent variable. The total investment cost is defined as the amount produced times the per unit cost in the investment year, which is the year that the company first invests into the project i. So, if the company invests for the first time into project i in the year 2024, the investment year is 2024.
Now, the problem is that the value of the investment year is crucial for the result, because the per unit costs Y change over time. When running the model, and calling the investment year rule (t_inv) on the instance of the model variables, the value for the investment year is generated correctly.
However, I use the t_inv rule also in the total_cost function and thus in the objective function. And when minimising the total costs, the wrong investment year is used, as can be seen in the model results. Investment year 2025 instead of 2022 is used. My guess is that this happens because I initialise the model variable X as 0. Therefore, when running the objective function 0 is used for the variable X and thus the investment years turn out to be 2025 (see t_inv rule for case when X=0). The function is not using the actual values for X but only the initial values. How can I now change the model such that I can achieve my desired results, and the objective function uses the correct investment years, not the initialised ones?
The mini working example is defined as follows:
from pyomo.environ import *

times = [2022, 2023, 2024, 2025]

projects = ["P1", "P2", "P3"]

model = AbstractModel()

model.time = Set(initialize = times)   # refers to time periods

model.project_type = Set(initialize = projects)   # refers to project types

model.Y = Param(model.project_type, model.time)   # cost per unit of investment

model.X = Var(model.project_type, model.time, initialize=0).  # amount of investment  


# Define rule to derive the investment year for project type 
def t_inv(i, times, X):
    all_inv_years = []  # Initialize the list to store all investment years for the specified project type
for t in times:
    if X[i, t].value > 0:
        all_inv_years.append(t)  # Append the investment year if investment is > 0
if all_inv_years:  # Check if there are any investment years for the specified project type
    inv_year = min(all_inv_years)  # Find the minimum investment year for the specified project type
    return inv_year  # Return the minimum investment year
else:
    return 2025  # Return 2025 if there are no investment years for the specified project 


#Define rule to calculate total costs for a given year t
def total_costs_rule(t, project_types, times, Y, X):
    # Define the terms inside the summation
    summation_terms = []
    summation_terms.extend([X[i, t] * Y[i, t_inv(i, times, X)] for i in project_types])  

    #Sum up all the terms
    total_cost = sum(summation_terms)

    #return total costs
    return total_cost


#Define Objective Function
def cost_rule(model):
    # compute total sum of future costs
    return sum( 
        total_costs_rule(t, model.project_type, model.time, model.Y, model.X) for t in model.time)

#Add cost_rule to the model as an objective function to minimize
model.cost = Objective(rule=cost_rule, sense=minimize)

#Yearly constraints on investments (i.e., investment limits for each year)
def investments_constraint_rule(model, t):
    return total_costs_rule(t, model.project_type, model.time, model.Y, model.X) >= 10

#add the rule to the model as a constraint
model.Investments_Constraint = Constraint(model.time, rule=investments_constraint_rule)

#feed in data
data= {None: {'Y': {('P1',2022): 1, ('P2',2022): 8, ('P3',2022): 12 , ('P1',2023): 0.9 , ('P2',2023): 7.5 ,
                ('P3',2023): 10, ('P1',2024): 0.8 ,('P2',2024): 7 ,('P3',2024): 8, ('P1',2025): 0.7 , 
                ('P2',2025): 6.5 ,('P3',2025): 6}}}

#create instance
instance = model.create_instance(data)

#solve
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
results = solver.solve(instance, tee=True)

#print model results
instance.pprint()

#print investment years
for i in instance.project_type:
print(t_inv(i, instance.time, instance.X))

I tried using an expression object for t_inv. This did not change anything. I also tried setting up t_inv as a variable and defining it in terms of variable X. But this also did not work. Maybe I did this incorrectly though, since I am still quite new to Pyomo.

Not to offend, but this isn't a valid math model.  The model that you are creating in pyomo cannot call other arbitrary functions.  The job of the model is to represent a static mathematical encoding of the problem that can be passed over to the solver.  You might want to search for other financial LP's on this site or elsewhere to get some examples.

The mini example does not represent the mathematical model I am creating, because I do not want to share it in public as it is still under development. I just created a numerical example that does not make sense at all but which still replicates the problem I am having in my actual mathematical model with the investment year. I hope someone can help me out with this Pyomo issue even though the mini mathematical model I am sharing here does not make much sense.

Not all valid Python is valid Pyomo code. Unfortunately, Pyomo is not able to generate a meaningful (or not so meaningful) error message. That is kind of a design problem. Functions should mainly have just expressions (no if-then-else). These if-then statements are executed at model generation time instead of during the solve. The best way to think about the problem is often not Python code, but rather a proper mathematical model.

Thank you for your meaningful comment, Erwin! This would mean that I have to transform my mathematical model by adding binary variables that indicate the investment year for each project type. That way my model becomes a mixed integer nonlinear problem (MINLP), and I can avoid using those if-else statements. Do I understand you correctly?
